# xdebug can't bind to port 9000 with WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, xdebug

I'm running: 
WAMP Server Version 2.5 
PHP Version 5.5.12
Aparche 2.4.9
Mysql 5.6.17
Windows 7
Xdebug 2.2.5

I've installed the recommended version of xdebug using the xdebug wizard that they offer on their website and configured my php.ini file like so:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host= "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "my path"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

Then I attempted to test xdebug using the method outlined here: https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/howto_check_xdebug_installation

It says create a file with the following code:

```
<?php
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 9000;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Unable to bind');
socket_listen($sock);
$client = socket_accept($sock);
echo "connection established: $client";
socket_close($client);
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Then access the file through a browser with the attribute ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=mysession

I've done that and I receive the following error message:

```
Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10048]: Only one usage of each socket address     (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. in stuff.php on line 5
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  242312  {main}( )   ..\stuff.php:0
2   0.0010  242976  socket_bind ( ) ..\stuff.php:5
Unable to bind
```

So I went to command prompt ran netstat -aon and found that a process with the pid of 3300 is listening on 0.0.0.0:9000. I checked task manager and it turns out that it's httpd.exe. I've tried to change

```
xdebug.remote_port=10000
```

but I get the same message.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: This problem could be that WAMPServer comes with XDEBUG already installed and configured. I guess your problem is you are trying to install it twice. Look at the bottom of the php.ini file. **Its already there**

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have resolved itself after a restart. I'm not sure what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a php file with a few commands, only to close the socket. Then I open it in another tab. So that tab that i was running before (with socket_listen), runs ok now. Try it. After some tests, the error stops at all, but appears again later. I think it's not a solution, but can help to understand the problem. This is the code for the second file:

```
<?php
$address = '127.0.0.1'; 
$port = 9000;
$socks = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_close($socks);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved checking the versions of php and xampp: it turned out, xampp was 32 bits installed in a 64 bits computer and I chose the wrong version of xdebug (it has to be 32 bits).